# Why can't I edit source code in Xamarin's Assembly Browser?

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget, package, nuget-package

So I've added a package via NuGet and I can use it just fine. I want to modify the code of the package but I cannot do it via Assembly Browser. Truth to be told, I don't seem to be able to do it with any code inside Packages directory.

Am I supposed to include these packages differently to edit them?

Is it possible to modify imported packages source code in Xamarin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Assembly Browser is designed for looking at compiled .NET code, because this code is compiled, it cannot be modified. If you want, you can decompile the package, then modify it, but doing so might cause legal issues. I would check the license (if there is any) to make sure your not breaking any laws